# JPA ...ToOne relationship skiping over intervening tables

Tags: jpa

Is it possible to map the relationship chain

[image: TableA --N:1--> TableB --N:1--> TableC]

using just `EntityA` and `EntityC`, without an explicit `EntityB`?

This is what I'm trying to avoid:

```java
EntityA entityA;
entityA.getEntityB().getEntityC();
```

Sometimes `EntityB` adds nothing to a model, and it would be useful to just skip over it entirely (for queries only; for insert/update/delete I understand it cant be done).

Is it even possible? How to do it?

```java
@Table("TableA")
class EntityA {
    /* @??? somehow declare TableB as a man-in-the-middle */
    private EntityC entityC;
}
```

As an extension/generalization to this question, suppose a longer chain (with intervening B1...Bn tables):

[image: TableA --N:1--> TableB1 ... TableBn --N:1--> TableC]

```java
@Table("TableA")
class EntityA {
    /* @??? somehow declare the whole chain TableB1...TableBn as a man-in-the-middle */
    private EntityC entityC;
}
```